# Trap and read $BASH_COMMAND but with yes/no

Tags: bash, shell, debugging

I am trying to run a simple script in debug mode.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'read -p "run: $BASH_COMMAND"'  DEBUG
command 1
command 2




 **Current output:** 
run: command 1 <press enter and the command executes>
run: command 2 <press enter and the command executes>
```

But I want to run this in a loop asking **yes/no** before every execution

Expected output:

```
run: command 1 yes/no? <input 'yes' + enter and the command executes>
run: command 2 yes/no? <input 'yes' + enter and the command executes>
```

I tried

```
trap [['read -p "run: $BASH_COMMAND" && "continue [y/n]" ' ; echo $REPLY)" == [Yy]* ]] && echo Continuing || echo Stopping DEBUG
```

but I am not able to figure it out.

Basically, I am trying to perform two read operation in trap/debug command and on second read i want to perform logical operation before executing.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, please? May be process substitution

Comment: See: [Prompt for confirmation for every command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72198/74329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
#! /bin/bash

confirm() {
    read -rp "run: $BASH_COMMAND, continue [y/n]: "
    if [[ "$REPLY" == [Yy]* ]]; then
        echo Continuing
    else
        echo Stopping DEBUG
        exit
    fi
}

trap confirm  DEBUG
command 1
command 2
```

Comment: @GursewakSingh: Or something like this in one line: `trap 'read -p "Run $BASH_COMMAND ?"; [[ "$REPLY" == [Yy] ]] || exit 1'  DEBUG`